# Why does "Int" exist, but not "Float"?

Tags: julia

I saw that when using `parse` for example, you can do this: `parse(Int, "123")` (`Int` exists), but I can't do `parse(Float, "12.3")` (`Float` doesn't exist).

Why doesn't `Float` exist as well then? What is the difference between `Int` and for example `Int64` or some other number after `Int` anyways (I know it has to do with the size, but how can you know when to use which)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that machines are either 32 bit or 64 bit. This is the size of pointers on these machines, and since pointers are just integers in hardware, it is also the "natural" integer size. Floating point arithmetic is different. (Almost) all computers have both FLoat32 and Float64, and the choice needs to be made based on application (how much range and accuracy you need). That said, you could always define `const Float = Float64` and then just use `Float`.

Comment: To be maybe even more clear: `Int16`, `Int32` and `Int64` (and others) always exist and describe 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit integer respectively. `Int` is an alias for one of `Int32` or `Int64`, depending on the hardware architecture.